# How can I avoid db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false?

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I want to avoid db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false. This has solved my problem "A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies". Is there any other way to solve this without using this?

This is my method in Controller

```
    public ActionResult GetData(int id)
    {
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        Products products = db.Products.Find(id);
        return Json(new { data = products }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This is my script

```
  $('#search').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Products/GetData/' + $('#id-product').val(),
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(data);

        }, error: function (response) {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
});
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Correct the loop, perhaps?

Comment: How can I do that?